# Flutter Autofill not working with Android biometric verification

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-autofill-manager

So, I have been having this issue for a while related to auto filling fields, below is a sample code:

```
 TextFormField(
 controller: _email,
  enableSuggestions: true,
  autocorrect: false,
  autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.email],
  focusNode: _emailFocusNode,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
  validator: (value) {
   if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
       return context.tr(pleaseEnterYourEmailText);
   } else if (!value.isValidEmail()) {
     return context.tr(pleaseEnterCorrectEmailText);
   }
     return null;
   },
   onChanged: (value) {
    _email.text = value;
   },
),
```

Now the issue is that clicking on this field opens up the saved accounts (for google & S23 Ultra) clicking on any of the saved accounts, it will ask for a Biometric verification, this is from the phone it self, now upon verifying, nothing happens, the fields does not populate at all, however, after typing one letter, the list shows up again, and if I select the previously selected saved account, it autofills the fields which is not the intended way at all.

I would very much appreciate some help on this matter as its been driving me nuts for the last few weeks.

Comment: did you try removing the function onChanged
?
In this context it seems unnesscary

Comment: @DEFL keeping it or removing it doesnt matter.